# Some programs looking very wrong

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, empathy, xfce

Some nautilus, empathy etc windows are having some lost graphic elements:

[image: See the titlebar]

[image: See the messages]

But some apps such as Xfce Terminal still looks normal

[image: This is proper]

Is this because of some package missing?

**EDIT**

After `sudo apt-get upgrade` the empathy theming is fixed, but nautilus is looking worse
[image: Menu bar]

This problem does not appear in Unity 2D

I've tried `gnome-tweak-tool` and switching themes and also, reinstalling the `light-themes` package

Launching any gtk+ app gets me this warn:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1597:20: Invalid animation description
```

Comment: No, Thats not needed :D

Comment: ... similar error reported here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/95016/ubuntu-11-10-resets-to-default-settings-after-reboot) - have you got kernel 3.2 installed?

Comment: Can you quote the line 1597 in gtk-widgets.css in Ambiance theme folder (gtk 3.0)?

Comment: Does it work with the default ambiance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned your ubuntu version and your window manager (unity 3d/compiz, unity 2d, metacity/gnome classic etc.)

### Steps

1. ***Backup*** your important data.
2. Please [create a new user](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/user-add.html), then [grant admin privileges](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/user-admin-change.html) and check if it works there. If it works, then the problem is somewhere in your user's home directory. Some program settings must have been altered.
3. (a) If you also have problems with the new user, try purging packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo dpkg -P --force-all ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-standard ubuntu-minimal
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-standard ubuntu-minimal
   sudo apt-get -f install
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   This is mostly harmless and will install any important packages you may have removed.
   Restart your pc and see if it's fixed.

   (b) If you do not have any problems with the new user, then some settings in your home configuration are causing trouble. Close any windows that you don't need and do not open anything.

   The following commands will **reset your gconf and dconf settings**. This includes window positions, default theme, desktop wallpaper/backgrounds, only very basic preferences in programs (e.g. nautilus will be in default view, not list view). but NOT your data nor any folder-specific settings.

   There is a small chance that something will go wrong, so please backup (#1) and have a live cd/usb somewhere in case you need to reinstall. Or use your new administrator account to fix the issues.

   The commands are:

   ```
   gconftool --shutdown
   killall -r -I -9 dconf
   killall -r -I -9 gconf
   mv .gconf gconf-backup
   mv .config/dconf config-dconf
   mv .cache/dconf cache-dconf
   ```

   Then reboot (do not do anything else, do not open/close any windows):

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

### Recovery

To recover your old settings:

```
gconftool --shutdown
killall -r -I -9 dconf
killall -r -I -9 gconf
mv gconf-backup .gconf
mv config-dconf .config/dconf
```

And reboot (do not do anything else, do not open/close any windows):

```
sudo reboot
```

### If it didn't work

- Did you by any chance install packages from any PPA or third-party repositories?

  These packages are not all checked, nor are all safe. Some exist for testing purposes only. I suggest you reinstall your system without any PPA until you become acquainted with the linux system (and how to recover).

Comment: yeah it worked i was also having some unusual window, by  the reset of gconf and dconf settings , it worked thanks a lot friend

Comment: It didnt work :(

Comment: Does the new created user have the same problems?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting GNOME UI settings?

If you open up a terminal and type:

```
tar czvf gnome-backup.tar.gz .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

And then run:

```
rm .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

That should hopefully restore your GNOME window settings back to normal. The above command first backs up the files about to be deleted, and then deletes them. You can always extract them back by running:

```
tar -zxvf gnome-backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: Nope.. Doesen't work